# issue is in Stripe Payment intigration

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, payment

why my stripe payment action show incomplete when i want to use stripe payment. am using in test mode.also i am using test card it also show snackbar(Payment successfull) when i added card detail.But why my stripe payment action show incomplete.[image: Stripe Action]

Is there any issue is with my code or any other issue .Please solve my issue.

```
 Future<void> intpayment(
      {required String email, required double amount})async{
    try{
      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
      String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
      final response= await http.post(Uri.parse("https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents")
          ,body:{
            "receipt_email": email,
            "amount": amount.toInt().toString(),
            "currency": "usd",
          },
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'key',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
      );
      var jsonresponse=jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(jsonresponse.toString());
      print(jsonresponse["client_secret"]);
      print("id="+jsonresponse["id"]);
      print("amount="+jsonresponse["amount"].toString());
    await  Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        merchantDisplayName: 'Zohaib',
paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonresponse['client_secret'],
        style: ThemeMode.dark,
customFlow: true,
      )).then((value) async{
        await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Payment").add({
            "id":FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
            "Client_secret":jsonresponse["client_secret"],
            "Client_id":jsonresponse["id"],
            "amount":jsonresponse["amount"].toString(),
            "Date_time":formattedDate,
            "Product_name":widget.productName
          });
        });
        print("payment successfull");
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "payment successfully",
        );
      });

    }
    catch(e){
      if (e is StripeException) {
        print(e);
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Stripe error $e",
        );
      }
      print(e);
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "$e",
      );
    }
  }
```

```
  ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
  intpayment(email: emailcontroller.text.toString(), amount: double.parse(widget.productPrice));
}
else{
  showDialog(context: context, builder: (builder){
    return AlertDialog(
content: Text("Make sure you enter valid email , Phone number or postal code..."),
      actions: [
        TextButton(onPressed: (){
Navigator.pop(context);
        }, child: Text("Cancel"))
      ],
    );
  });
}

                  },
                  child: Text("Pay ${widget.productPrice}\$"),
                ),
```

Comment: what's the [status](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status) of the PaymentIntent?

Comment: The status of payment intent is 200.

Comment: Can you please solve my issue

Comment: 200 is the response status. I'm asking about the status of the PaymentIntent, which is one of `requires_payment_method`, `requires_confirmation`, `requires_action`, `processing`, `requires_capture`, `canceled`, or `succeeded` - https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status. Once you know the status of the PaymentIntent, you'll know what steps you need to take : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents#intent-statuses

Answer (score 0):

Comment "customFlow: true," then try. Otherwise, hover on "i" near Incomplete and check what is the exact problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).